# Closure events bubble down

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, google-closure, google-closure-library

I'm working on a web app in Google closure where the structure is something like this:

```
App
  + Control Pane
  |  + Search Box
  |  + Search Button
  + Result Pane
     + Results
     + Next Page Link
```

The actual component structure is quite a bit more complex. The important point is that there are many different components all over the component tree that can initiate certain actions. In this example, hitting enter in `Search Box`, pressing `Search Button`, or hitting `Next Page` all require a query to be made.

This is simple enough to handle. Any child anywhere in the component tree can do

```
this.dispatchEvent(App.EventType.ACTION, ...)
```

`App` will be able to listen to it when the event propagates upwards. The problem is the other direction: When `App` receives data from its query, it must push it to all children.

It seems very brittle for `App` to try to push directly to `Search box` and `Results`, as their location in the component tree is subject to change. What I'd like to do is fire an `App.EventType.DATA_RECEIVED` event and have all children (and sub-children, etc.) hear it.

The only way to do this in google closure that I've been able to find is to make a global public singleton instance of `App` and use as the source for all `App.EventType.DATA_RECEIVED` events, or to plumb `App` through to all children and subchildren.

Both of these are messy and brittle in their own way.

Is there a simple way in closure to dispatch events that bubble downwards?

Comment: this sounds more like a design decision to me. I assume the data you want to make availiable to the rest of the app is part of a model, so why don't you hook the individual components up to listen to the bits of the model they are interested in and parse the data where you get it and have the model dispatch change events. ala binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a very satisfactory answer, but it's what I settled on:

There's no good way to communicate such things *down* the component tree. Even closure itself bumps into this problem, passing `opt_domHelper` down the tree to every subcomponent.

My suggestion is to subclass `goog.ui.Component` for your app and create a `myapp.Environment` class, which contains both `opt_domHelper` and other environment variables, such as one event listener designated as the application's event channel.

It's not a *good* solution, per se, but it's the least of all possible evils. And if you've already been dutifully passing `opt_domHelper` everywhere, then it's no worse a problem: that plumbing becomes more extensible, and the `opt_domHelper` itself is hidden from implementors (who now pass around `environment` instead).